# javafx reading data from TableView

Tags: java

i have been trying to finish up my app that is a ware house stock management system. i have this tableView i have created and i need the user to be able to select a row and then some of this data displayed in a textfields. i have used a change listener but its not giving what i want. the selection is specific to which cell of the row is clecked. i dont want this. irrespective of which cell is clicked, i want to always get data from same columns of the selected row.

take a look at my code

///table for the products and quantities availabe
        final Label label = new Label("Products and available quantities");
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));
        label.setId("listHeader");

```
    final TableView<prodreq> reqProd=new TableView<>();
    reqProd.setId("prodt");
    final ObservableList<prodreq>datareq=
            FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    reqProd.setPrefHeight(3*(gH/4.5));
    reqProd.setEditable(false);

    TableColumn itemcode=new TableColumn("Item Code");
    itemcode.setPrefWidth(2*((0.75*gW)/5-((0.75*gW)/5)/2));
    itemcode.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<prodreq,String>("itemcode"));


    TableColumn item=new TableColumn("Item");
    item.setPrefWidth((0.75*gW)/5+((0.75*gW)/5)/2);
    item.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<prodreq,String>("item"));


    TableColumn qty=new TableColumn("Qty 1");
    qty.setPrefWidth((0.75*gW)/5-((0.75*gW)/5)/2);
    qty.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<prodreq,String>("qty"));

    TableColumn qty2=new TableColumn("Qty 2");
    qty2.setPrefWidth((0.75*gW)/5-((0.75*gW)/5)/2);
    qty2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<prodreq,String>("qty"));

    TableColumn category=new TableColumn("Category");
    category.setPrefWidth((0.75*gW)/5+((0.75*gW)/5)/2);
    category.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<prodreq,String>("category"));


    reqProd.getColumns().addAll(itemcode,item,qty,qty2,category);
    reqProd.setItems(datareq);
```

the table works fine am able to populate it with data from DB. this code below is my 
listener

```
 {   reqProd.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
@Override
public void changed(ObservableValue observableValue, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
    //Check whether item is selected and set value of selected item to Label
    if(reqProd.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null) 
    {    
       TableViewSelectionModel selectionModel = reqProd.getSelectionModel();
       ObservableList selectedCells = selectionModel.getSelectedCells();
       TablePosition tablePosition = (TablePosition) selectedCells.get(0);
       Object val = tablePosition.getTableColumn().getCellData(newValue);
       System.out.println("" + val);
     }
     }
 });}
```

an when i run the prog, the out put is the data in the cell that i click on...but then the whole row is selected and what i want id to always obtain the data in the first column cell of the selected row.

thanks in advance for ur help.